# My scroll bar on userform can't be scrolled

Tags: vba, excel

[image]
I have a userform that was created with a scrollbar. This scrollbar can scroll only when I use mouse courser to drag it. However, I find that it cannot be scrolled with the mouse scroll (scroll wheel).

**How do I solve it ?**

Answer (score 1):

Using the mouse wheel to scroll in UserForms and UserForm Controls is not enabled by default. You actually have to code the action into your UserForm. This [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=184493) and this [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/358378-code-mouse-wheel-visual-basic-applications.html) both describe how you can do this.

However, I have found it to be unstable and using it crashes most of my excel sessions.